# 'Scheme already exists: Identity.Application' when adding identity when adding another user identity service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have Application User which inherits from Identity User

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string IDNumber { get; set; }
        public string PhysicalAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

and Another VendorUser which inherits from ApplicationUser

```
    public class VendorUser : ApplicationUser
    {
        public int? VendorUserId { get; set; }
        public int CardNumber { get; set; }
        public string PhotoIDUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

If I Register the services in the startup.cs file like:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
services.AddIdentity<VendorUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
```

I got the error above.

If its unable to resolve the service of the VendorUser if I don't. How do I resolve the service of the VendorUser without getting that error

Comment: Could you please share the details AppDbContext? Do you create two table one for ApplicationUser  and another for VendorUser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot repeatedly use AddIdentity to add an identity.

ASP.NET Core provides a built-in method:`AddIdentityCore<TUser>`

You can use it like this:

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
 services.AddIdentityCore<VendorUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Hope this can help you.